# I want to display specific column using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

need help. I am trying to link former storage table with former ratio table. Here is my code. But it always show syntax error.
my table:
former storage:

|IndexId|Date|from_section|to section|

former ratio:

|IndexId|Date|BeforeFormerID1|BeforeFormerID2|AfterFormerID1|AfterFormerID2|

my code:

$sql = "SELECT * `former storage`.`IndexID`, `Date`, `from_section`, `to_section`, `BeforeFormerID1`, `BeforeFormerID2`, `AfterFormerID1`,`AfterFormerID2` FROM `former storage` INNER JOIN  `former ratio` ON `former storage`.`IndexID` = `former ratio`.`IndexID`";

Comment: do the tablenames really have spaces in them ? `former ratio` ?

Comment: yes have space. should i remove the space?

Comment: If you can, yes rename both tables and the `to section` column so they do not have spaces in the names. Convention is generally to use lowersnakecase for table- and columnames, so `from_section` is well named, the tables could be `former_storage` and such. use of capitals and spaces makes your life a lot harder ; but i don't know how much of that is fully up to you of course.

Comment: already remove the space but still can't run

Comment: If your table/column names in database is already with spaces, removing (the spaces) in the query will only tell you that the table don't exists. You need to rename the table by running `RENAME TABLE \`former storage\` TO former_storage;`. That if you have access to do so and this is not a production table. If this is a production table and you change it's name, that will crash all the process using it and you'll need to change all query to adapt the new table name(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's basically 3 problems with the query:

- (1) the asterisk (`*`) shouldn't be there;
- (2) for the `Date` column you should specify from what table it comes (as they both have that column)
- (3) the spaces in the 2 tablenames and 1 columnname break the query; you either have to escape the table- and columnnames (between backticks), or (preferably) rename them.

Without changing the table- and column names, the right query would be:

```
       SELECT `former storage`.`IndexID`
            , `former storage`.`Date`
            , `from_section`, `to section`
            , `BeforeFormerID1`, `BeforeFormerID2`
            , `AfterFormerID1`,  `AfterFormerID2`
         FROM `former storage`
   INNER JOIN `former ratio`
           ON `former ratio`.`IndexID` = `former storage`.`IndexID`
```

But if you improve some of the column names then most of those backticks are no longer necessary.